# selenium catch all the link with css selector result

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I practice how to use selenium and it can catch the first link.
But I hope it can catch all the link

Because the structure is the same,it should catch all links

```
<div class='dah'>
   <section>
       <div class='media'><a href='http://www.test.tw/event/22'></a>
   <section>
   <section>
       <div class='media'><a href='http://www.test.tw/event/23'></a>
   <section>
   <section>
       <div class='media'><a href='http://www.test.tw/event/24'></a>
   <section>
   <section>
       <div class='media'><a href='http://www.test.tw/event/25'></a>
   <section>
 <div>
```

How can I do?

Here is my code in terminal:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> d = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> d.get('http://www.test.com/')
>>> next = d.find_element_by_css_selector("div.hah section div.media a")
>>> next.get_attribute("href")    
u'http://www.test.tw/event/22'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find_elements_by_css_selector`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector) (element **s**): (Selenium provides `find_element_*` and `find_elements_*`)

```
elements = d.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.hah section div.media a")
[a.get_attribute("href") for a in elements]
```